# Proving that $(\mathbb{R}^n, d_{\infty})$ is a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I am trying to show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a metric space with metric $d_{\infty} (p,q) = \max\{|p_i - q_i|\}$. The only condition I'm a bit stuck on proving is the triangle inequality, $d_{\infty} (p,q) \leq d_{\infty} (p,r) + d_{\infty} (r,q)$.

For any $i$, I have
$$ 
|p_i - q_i| \leq |p_i - r_i| + |r_i - q_i|,
$$
because the Euclidean metric satisfies the triangle inequality. Now I want to "take the maximum over $i$" of both sides, but this is not very rigorous to say. Surely if this holds for all $i$, I should be able to say
$$
\max |p_i - q_i| \leq \max\left(|p_i - r_i| + |r_i - q_i|\right),
$$
and because the maximum of a sum is less than or equal to the sum of the maximums, we get the result.

My question is how to rigorously justify this property of maximums. I could say that $|p_i - r_i| \leq \max(|p_i - r_i|)$ and $|r_i - q_i| \leq \max (|r_i - q_i|)$, but that still leaves the left-hand side.

Comment: Well, notice that for each $i$, $\left| p_i - r_i \right| + \left| r_i - q_i \right| \leq \max \left\lbrace \left| p_i - r_i \right| \right\rbrace + \max \left\lbrace \left| r_i - q_i \right| \right\rbrace$. The result now follows easily.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I understand this step, but I don't understand how the full result follows from this. We have from this that $|p_i - r_i| \leq \max\{|p_i - r_i|\} + \max\{|r_i - q_i|\}$ for every $i$. How can we insert the maximum on the left-hand side?

Comment: Because the right hand side is an upper bound for the set $\left\lbrace \left| p_i - q_i \right| \right\rbrace$. Hence, the maximum (supremum) is less than or equal to the upper bound.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh That makes sense. Is it fair to say that I'm invoking the properties of supremum here to conclude this? The supremum is surely less than or equal to any other upper bound, and this just happens to be a maximum because it's a finite set.